# odd react-native promise rejection

Tags: react-native, expo

I keep getting this error, but I can't track it down even with sentry

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
- node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:473:29 in xhr.onerror
- node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:39 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:574:29 in setReadyState
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:388:25 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

How can I track this down?

Comment: whats your react-native version?

Comment: 1.3.1

https://gist.github.com/iamjonbradley/3b801bd26ac717ab0759a18780e60d79

Comment: You could check in your app where you make a request call. In the error above, there is a request that throw the error, but your app did not handle the error (try/catch)

Comment: do previous your network request works?